# Spring Data Rest: Test for deleteByName by using CURL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I believe deleteByName is supported in spring data rest. In one of my project, I have implemented **void deleteByName(@Param("name")String personName)**. In order to test it, I am using "curl url/search/deleteByName?name=somename". However, it shows me an error and delete operation is not successful. If I want to test the function by using curl, Is this the way I should test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need to use DELETE with curl in this case.

You can indeed use curl as shown below.

**curl  url/search/deleteByName?name=somename**. The error has nothing to do with the way you are testing.